# problem importing an image into R markdown file

Tags: image, r-markdown, knitr

I am learning R markdown and currently trying to add an image as per this excellent site https://www.earthdatascience.org/courses/earth-analytics/document-your-science/add-images-to-rmarkdown-report/
I have saved the example dog image but am having problems importing it into the simplest R markdown file. I have tried several ways (not just the way described on the site). I use knitr in Rstudio.

The first way that doesnt work is this where I give the subfolder under my working directory (I have also tried it without the slash before "images" and by giving the full path name).

```
---
title: "myImage"
output: html_document
---
This is a markdown to display an image

![an image caption Source: Ultimate Funny Dog Videos Compilation 2013.](/images/silly-dog.png)
```

I have also tried this but this doesnt work either

````
---
title: "myImage"
output: html_document
---

This is a markdown to display an image

```{r}
knitr::include_graphics("C:/Users/myname/Documents/Programs//R/images/silly-dog.png")
```
````

In both cases R says it can't find the image file "File /images/silly-dog.png not found in resource path" (but it is there - in the images subfolder)
many thanks for any tips

Comment: Use a double backslash for Windows... ```knitr::include_graphics("C:\\Folder1\\Folder2\\Pic.png")```

Comment: ah thanks, manro - thats a good idea

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't seem to work for me, I get the same "File images\silly-dog.png not found in resource path" with the following

Comment: ![an image caption Source: Ultimate Funny Dog Videos Compilation 2013.](images\\silly-dog.png)

Comment: Check the availability of this picture in your folder

Comment: thanks manro, it  certainly seems to be in the images subfolder of my working directory with the name I specify ... whether I'm specifying the folder wrong but I've tried full path names and relative to working directory with a variety of slashes .. I'll research more or find a tutorial example that works that might shed light .. thanks again

Answer (score 0):

my apologies I have found the problem and it is a silly one.
When I right clicked on my image in the folder and copied the path I discovered the file was actually called silly-dog.png.jpg
this now works

```
![an image caption Source: Ultimate Funny Dog Videos Compilation 2013.](/Users/berna/Documents/Programs/R/images/silly-dog.png.jpg)
```

sorry to have taken your time